# European online stores selling electronics

Tags: merchants, ecommerce, europe

I know bitcoinstore.com is the heaven for bitcoin loving geeks to buy their gadget. However I'd like to find similar electronics stores in European Union area to avoid extra custom fees.

Are there any bitcoin-friendly stores in EU?

Answer (score 2):

Through websearch I have found [e4btc.com](https://e4btc.com/). They seem to be based in Berlin.

I do not have any further experience or information about their offers, nor am I affiliated to them in any way.

Answer (score 2):

I've made several purchases from [bitelectronics.net](http://bitelectronics.net/). As a bonus, Mikko, they're based in your (and my) country!

Comment: bitelectronics.net seems to have shut down.